# Hide labels in pie charts (MS Chart for .Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-visualization, mschart

[image: ugly pie chart]

I can't seem to find the property that controls visibility of labels in pie charts. I need to turn the labels off as the information is available in the legend.

Anyone know what property I can use in code behind?

I tried setting the series labels to nothing `Chart1.Series[i].Label = string.Empty;` but the labels seem to show up anyway.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
Chart1.Series[i]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
```

works too, and doesn't need to be set for each datapoint.

Answer (score 10):

This can also be done in the UI by

1. Opening the Series editor window (ellipsis button in the main properties panel)
2. Selecting the wanted series
3. Expanding the `CustomProperties` property
4. Choosing `Disabled`

[image: Example]

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/32ccd993-5f43-47a3-bcbc-e772a13a87fe

It turns out there is an obscure DataPointCustomProperty called PieLabelStyle that governs label visibility in pie charts. Worse still, the property must be set on each data point.

```
for (var i = 0; i < chart.Series.Count; i++) 
    for (var j = 0; j < chart.Series[i].Points.Count; j++)
        chart.Series[i].Points[j]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
```

Answer (score 7):

Changing chart custom properties will do the trick as well and no coding is needed

```
<asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Pie" CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Disabled">
```

Answer (score 2):

...and Ben's answer in VB.NET format:

```
Chart1.Series(0)("PieLabelStyle") = "Disabled"
```

works fine for setting whole series

Answer (score 1):

May be this website solve your problem

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
     {
        // Insert code to create basic pie chart
        // See my blog post entitled "Pie Charts in ASP.NET" for full source code

```
     // Set pie labels to be outside the pie chart
     this.Chart2.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";

     // Set border width so that labels are shown on the outside
     this.Chart2.Series[0].BorderWidth = 1;
     this.Chart2.Series[0].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);

     // Add a legend to the chart and dock it to the bottom-center
     this.Chart2.Legends.Add("Legend1");
     this.Chart2.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
     this.Chart2.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
     this.Chart2.Legends[0].Alignment = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;

     // Set the legend to display pie chart values as percentages
     // Again, the P2 indicates a precision of 2 decimals
     this.Chart2.Series[0].LegendText = "#PERCENT{P2}";

     // By sorting the data points, they show up in proper ascending order in the legend
     this.Chart2.DataManipulator.Sort(PointSortOrder.Descending, Chart2.Series[0]);
 }
```

Also visit this website i also take this code from that website very nice tutorial on mscharts 
http://betterdashboards.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/display-percentages-on-a-pie-char

Answer (score 0):

```
objChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Have you tested this with pie charts? It is valid for most chart types but back in February it did not affect pie charts. Has this changed?

Answer (score 0):

For C# the following code works well for all points in the serie.

```
chart1.Series[seriesname]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).