# Label overlapping in pie chart

Tags: vb.net, charts

```
With Chart2
    .Series.Clear()
    .Titles.Clear()
    .Series.Add("Series1")
   
End With

Dim series As Series = Chart2.Series("Series1")
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
Chart2.DataSource = dt

With Chart2

    .ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True

    .Series(0).XValueMember = "AccountName"
    .Series(0).YValueMembers = "PolicyAmount"
    .Series(0).IsValueShownAsLabel = True
    .Series(0).Label = "(#VALY) #PERCENT"

    .Series(0).LegendText = "#VALX (#VALY)(#PERCENT)"
    .Series(0)("PieLabelStyle") = "inside"
    .Series(0).Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 9, FontStyle.Bold)


    '.Series(0).LabelForeColor = Color.White
    .Titles(0).Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
    .Legends(0).Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 9, FontStyle.Bold)

End With
```

[image]

Is there a property which can arrange these labels within the coloured area. is there a angle property or like something m i missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSChart: Pie Chart Label Overlapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497392/mschart-pie-chart-label-overlapping-issue)